[Airflow]: Dynamic Task Mapping on DockerOperator using Xcoms
I am creating a dag that should do the following:

fetch event ids
for each event id, fetch event details ( DockerOperator )

The code below is my attempt to do what I want:
from datetime import datetime

from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker import DockerOperator



With Dag(
    start_date=datetime(2024, 11, 1),
    schedule="@daily",
):
    task_fetch_ids = PythonOperator(
        task_id="fetch_detail",
        ...)


    task_fetch_detail = DockerOperator(
        task_id="fetch_detail",
        image="image:v1",
        ).expand(
            command=[f"fetch-event --event-id  {event_id}" for event_id in "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='task_fetch_ids', key='return_value') }}"]
        )


    task_fetch_ids >> task_fetch_detail



The above clearly doesn't work because I am looping through a string.
What is the correct syntax ?

you must adapt the xcom return to the args of the dynamic task mapping operator

from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker import DockerOperator

dag = DAG(
    dag_id="docker_dag",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=days_ago(1),
)
with dag:
    def fn_get_work():
        return ["a", "b", "c"]


    get_work_task = PythonOperator(task_id="get_work",
                                   python_callable=fn_get_work
                                   )


    def fn_build(work):
        rst = []
        for i in work:
            rst.append(f"fetch-event --event-id {i}")
        return rst


    build_work_task = PythonOperator(task_id="build_work",
                                     python_callable=fn_build,
                                     op_kwargs={"work": get_work_task.output})

    run_work_task = DockerOperator.partial(
        task_id="run_work",
        image="alpine:3.16.2",
    ).expand(command=build_work_task.output)

    get_work_task >> build_work_task >> run_work_task



Works like a charm, thanks
